# django include template repeated in all url but get data from main url

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

i have one html template for my main body and in every url this main body is fixed. but the data from this fixed body is show only in main url or in one url
like this i have a inbox and number of message on it
[inbox message number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x057M.png)

in every url i have this message but in main url or view i send data to template for example if yo go to main url the number on inbox show but if you go to another url because the data is not in your view yo dont have number
how can i fix this !!?
or my question is how include template get data from special url in every url in django!?

Answer (score 0):

No, Django does not provide any special `URL` concepts, But you can archive those things like this...

#### views.py

```
def navbar_counters(request):
    a={'inbox':10,'mesages':20}
    return a


def Oneview(request):
    counters= navbar_counters(request)   
    context = {'counters':counters}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def Twoview(request):
    counters= navbar_counters(request)   
    context = {'counters':counters}
    return render(re
```

quest,'page2.html',context)

#### index.html

```html
    {% block body %}
    <h1>Page - 1</h1>
         <div class="container-fluid mt-5 ">
            <div>
                {% for i,j in counters.items %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary position-relative ms-5 ">
                    {{i}}
                    <span class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-danger">
                      {{j}}+
                    </span>
                </button>
                {% endfor %}
            </div> 
         </div>
    {% endblock body %}
```

#### browser Output

[image]

### NOTE - You need to call `navbar_counters(request)` function in every view function, I mean you need to call below code snippet in every views function.

```py
    counters= navbar_counters(request)   
    context = {'counters':counters}
```